# Connection refused - connect(2) for "freegeoip.net" port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

### Environment

- Rails 4.0.4
- Ruby 2.0.1
- Geocoder gem

### Issue

Today my app is down and I am not able to resolve the issue, in the log:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "freegeoip.net" port 80):
```

Looks like it's related so the Geocoder gem

Most bizarre if that the issue doesn't happen on development environment.

I have checked the `freegeoip` and looks like it's down, this said I am not sure why it should prevent my app from running

```
$ curl http://freegeoip.net 
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Comment: [www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/freegeoip.net) is a great debugging tool to keep in your bookmarks

Comment: Yep it's down, they should be some graceful way of handling this issue.

Comment: Seems freegeoip.net is down a lot lately :(

Answer (score 3):

How I resolved it

```
begin
  @location =  "#{request.location.city} #{request.location.country_code}"
rescue => e
  # handle the error here
  logger.debug "http://freegeoip.net must be down!"
  logger.debug e.message
end
```